# Can SetDIBits draw directly to a screen or monitor?

Tags: c++, windows

(Might seem like a silly question) Can [SetDIBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd162973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) be used to directly alter pixels on the monitor without a handle to a window?

Every reference I can find uses SetDIBits in terms of a HWND or a printer, but not on a HDC directly. For example using a HDC of the desktop would I be able to draw directly to the screen without using a window?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. It is the HBITMAP parameter that is being updated, not the HDC.